# vba get file names with same opening characters in one row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select the files and list the file name in array (put file names with same first 9 characters in same row). I got error 400. "1004 Application defined / object defined error" Please advise.

error message

[image: 1]

list of file names template

[image: 2]

Here is my code:

```
Sub SelectFileName()
    
    Dim fnam As Variant
    ' fnam is an array of files returned from GetOpenFileName
    ' note that fnam is of type boolean if no array is returned.
    ' That is, if the user clicks on cancel in the file open dialog box, fnam is set to FALSE
    
    Dim b As Integer 'counter for filname array
    
    Dim FSO As Object 'Get file name
    Dim FileName As String
     Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
 
    fnam = Application.GetOpenFilename("all files (*.*), *.*", 1, _
    "Select Files to Fill Range", "Get Data", True)
    
    If TypeName(fnam) = "Boolean" And Not (IsArray(fnam)) Then Exit Sub
    
    'if user hits cancel, then end
 
 Dim last_row As Long
 Dim last_column As Long
 
    For b = 1 To UBound(fnam)
         last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         For c = 1 To last_row
             last_column = Cells(c, Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column
             ' print out the filename (with path) into first column of new sheet
             If ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, "D").Value = Mid(fnam(b), 1, Len(Cells(b + 1, "D"))) Then
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, c + 1) = FSO.GetFileName(fnam(b))
             End If
            'Get File Name
         Next
    Next 
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us the line that throws the error, and add the description of error 400 - not everyone knows all error codes by heart

Comment: Thank you, the error message is just "400". And then I have tried to run inside the scripe and get error "1004 Application defined / object defined error". I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```vb
Sub SelectFileName()
    
    Dim fnam As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim FSO As Object 'Get file name
    Dim FileName As String, voucher
    Dim b As Long, c As Long
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
    fnam = Application.GetOpenFilename("all files (*.*), *.*", 1, _
                       "Select Files to Fill Range", "Get Data", True)
    'if user hits cancel, then end
    If TypeName(fnam) = "Boolean" And Not (IsArray(fnam)) Then Exit Sub
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific sheet name
    
    For b = 1 To UBound(fnam)                               'loop selected files
        FileName = FSO.GetFileName(fnam(b))                 'get file name from path 
        For c = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'loop over voucher numbers
            voucher = UCase(ws.Cells(c, "D").Value)                'read the voucher #
            If UCase(Left(FileName, Len(voucher))) = voucher Then  'check for match (case-insensitive)
                ws.Cells(c, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = FileName
            End If
        Next c
    Next b

End Sub
```